# Как сделать ajax запрос в reactjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

просмотрел кучу статей, как то все очень усложнено

как реализовать ajax запрос в `react`?

есть ли рабочий пример?

`UPDATE`

использую `redux`

пытаюсь обновить `store` через `ajax`

```
var React = require("react");
var ReactDOM = require("react-dom");
var redux = require("redux");
var Provider = require("react-redux").Provider;
var reducer = require("./reducer");
var AppView = require("./appview");
var ReduxThunk = require('redux-thunk').default;

var store = redux.createStore(reducer, redux.compose(redux.applyMiddleware(ReduxThunk)));

store.dispatch(getItems());

function getItems() {
  fetch('/items.json')
    .then(function(response) {
      return response.json();
     })
    .then(function(data) {
      console.log(data);

      return {
        type: "SET_STATE",
        state: {
          items: data.items
        }
      }
    })
    .catch( alert );  
}


ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <AppView />
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById("container")
);
```

получаю ошибку:

> Uncaught Error: Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware
>   for async actions

данные из `JSON` считались, но как правильно их отдать в `store`?

Comment: React - это про View, а не про запросы.

Comment: Вы можете использовать XHR, `$ajax`, `fetch`, rest.js, обмотать это все в redux-thunk (если используете redux),  Relay/GraphQL - куча вариантов.

Comment: Может быть, это наведет на конкретный вопрос: http://andrewhfarmer.com/react-ajax-best-practices/

Comment: @Nofate, спасибо. Обновил вопрос.

Comment: Вам нужно учить js, на лицо не понимание того с чего начинаются книжки - асинхронность. Вопрос к реакту не относится. Раньше были вопросы - "что учить js или jq", а теперь будут - "что учить js или react", а то и вообще - "что учить js или redux".

Comment: @OlmerDale. не передергивайте. Как я понимаю `redux-thunk` как раз и используется для решения этого. Вопрос как его правильно приготовить. В этом я еще плаваю.

Comment: передергиваете как раз Вы! Я помню Ваш предыдущий вопрос и если Вы не прыгаете с одного места на другое, то Вы задали не тот вопрос. Да и код говорит что Вы не понимаете что такое асинхронность и не можете пользоваться гуглом, ведь существует тысяча русскоязычных мануалов по реакту и редаксу.

Comment: @OlmerDale, ссылку дайте, на работающий пример

Comment: Я не могу дать ссылку на работающий пример, так как заведомо их не проверял на работоспособность. В гугле полно информации-статей-книг как создать приложение с нуля. И ладно бы два года назад сейчас их очень много и просить погуглить за Вас это уже слишком. Хотя здесь полного гугл ботов может кто-то и погуглит. И Вам дали почти нужный ответ, остается лишь прочитать мои предыдущие советы и совместить.

Answer (score 1):

Для этой цели я использую axios. Создаете экшн:

```
 import axios from 'axios'

 import {
   AJAX_REQUEST,
   AJAX_SUCCESS,
   AJAX_ERROR
 } from '../constants/appConstants'

 export function ajaxRequestFunction(requestData) {
     var url = 'http://youURL';
     var request = requestData;
     return (dispatch) => {
         dispatch({
             type: AJAX_REQUEST,
             payload: {}
         })
         axios.post(url, request)
             .then(result => {
                 dispatch({
                     type: AJAX_SUCCESS,
                     payload: {
                         result: result.data,
                     }
                 })
             })
             .catch(error => {
                 dispatch({
                     type: AJAX_ERROR,
                     payload: {},
                     errors: error
                 })
             })
     }
 }
```

В редюсере слушаете соответствующие события и менятете стейт:

```
import {
   AJAX_REQUEST,
   AJAX_SUCCESS,
   AJAX_ERROR
} from '../constants/appConstants'

const initialState = {
    data: false,
}

export default function sideNav(state = initialState, action) {
    var newState
    switch (action.type) {
        case AJAX_SUCCESS:
            return { ...state, data: action.payload.result}
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

Не забудьте определить константы евентов в ./constants/appConstants:

```
export const AJAX_REQUEST = 'AJAX_REQUEST'
export const AJAX_SUCCESS= 'AJAX_SUCCESS'
export const AJAX_ERROR= 'AJAX_ERROR'
```

Ну и конечно вызов экшна в компоненте:

```
import React, { Component} from 'react'
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import * as appActions from '../../../actions/appActions'

class pageComponent extends Component {

    clickHandler(){
        const {ajaxRequestFunction} = this.props.appActions;
        let request = "привет"
        ajaxRequestFunction(request);
    }

    render() {
        return <div>
            <div onclick={this.clickHandler.bind(this)}>Кликни меня</div>
        </div>
    }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        app: state.app,
    }
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return {
        appActions: bindActionCreators(appActions, dispatch),
    }
}


export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(pageComponent)
```

Comment: Спасибо. А покажите, пожалуйста, вызов `ajaxRequestFunction`

Comment: Пожалуйста. Обновил ответ.

Comment: fetch круче чем axios

Comment: хм... они просто немного разные http://andrewhfarmer.com/ajax-libraries/

Comment: они не просто разные, они очень разные. axios был крут до появления fetch, ведь он, наверное единственный, был по настоящему изоморфным. Но теперь есть fetch, который является нативным и есть isomorphic-fetch, который его прекрасно дополняет и однозначно отправляет axios в технический нокаут.

Comment: @OlmerDale, спасибо за информацию! Теперь мне прямо тоже очень хочется попробовать fetch)) А когда не надо будет учитывать ie11, тогда fetch вообще станет праздником)

Comment: Когда Вы используете axios, то подключаете библиотеку и это нормально. Что мешает подключить для ie11 полифил?