# Как обновить store из Component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

по задумке дизайнера форма должна обновляться при выборе значения из `<select/>`

как в парадигме react, redux обновить `store` из `component` ?

Comment: Как всегда - вызвать функцию из `props`, которая вызовет `dispatch`.

Comment: @YozhEzhi, это я понимаю, вопрос где хранить `store` ? получается что он глобальный объект, но мне кажется есть другой способ

Comment: В парадигме Редакс - состояние приложения хранится в одном хранилище. Я так и не понял ваш вопрос.

Comment: @YozhEzhi, у меня хранилище создается в App.jsx `var store = redux.createStore(reducer);` и из компонента оно не видно, приходится делать `window.store = redux.createStore(reducer);` и мне кажется так не правильно

Comment: Конечно, так не правильно. Действия нужно передавать в свойствах компоненту. Т.е. нужно связать Реакт и Редакс через Реакт-редакс.

Comment: https://rajdee.gitbooks.io/redux-in-russian/content/docs/basics/UsageWithReact.html#компоненты-контейнеры - mapDispatchToProps() - вы реализовали такое?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/649794/230293 - в этом ответе вам привели полный код, как нужно реализовывать обновление Хранилища.